# Visual Basic Random Name Generator function

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, random, visual-studio-2013

Ok, working with Visual Basic (in Visual Studio Express 2013, if that makes a difference). I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of first names from a text file, and inserts each line into an index in an array. What I'm getting is the particular index, rather than the string assigned to that index.

```
    Private Sub btnAutofill_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAutofill.Click

        Dim ranFname As String = RandomFname(ranFname)
        Dim ranLname As String = RandomLname(ranLname)

        txtCustFname.Text = ranFname
        txtCustLname.Text = ranLname

    End Sub

    Private Function RandomFname(ByRef ranFname As String) As String

        Dim userPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
        Dim fname() As String
        Dim rand As New Random()

        fname = IO.File.ReadAllLines(userPath & "\OneDrive\Coding\Visual Studio\firstNames.txt")
        ranFname = rand.Next(0, fname.Length - 1)
        Return ranFname

    End Function

    Private Function RandomLname(ByRef ranLname As String) As String

        Dim userPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
        Dim lname() As String
        Dim rand As New Random()
        lname = IO.File.ReadAllLines(userPath & "\OneDrive\Coding\Visual Studio\lastNames.txt")
        ranLname = rand.Next(0, lname.Length - 1)
        Return ranLname

    End Function
```

Now, when I click the button for autofill, instead of my textboxes having:

First Name: **Mary**   Last Name: **Jones**

I get:

First Name: **68**   Last Name: **68**

I also dont know why it's making it the same number every time, it should be random.

So obviously, I'm on the wrong track. Somebody mind helping me out?

Comment: Don't recreate the Random object each time, that's whats causing the number problem. Create it once and pass it as a parameter instead. Also I'd pass the file name as a parameter and have a single name function as they are doing the same thing just on different files.

Comment: Replace `Return ranLname` with `Return lname (ranLname)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadAllLines()` returns an array, you just want a random position from this array:

```
Private Function RandomFname(ByRef ranFname As String) As String

    Dim userPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
    Dim fname() As String
    Dim rand As New Random()

    fname = IO.File.ReadAllLines(userPath & "\OneDrive\Coding\Visual Studio\firstNames.txt")
    Return fname(rand.Next(0, fname.Length - 1))

End Function
```

*I also dont know why it's making it the same number every time, it should be random.*

If you want a different number each time, instantiate a single `Random` once that both methods use, or instantiate each `Random` with the overload that allows you to supply your own seed:

```
Dim rand As New Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
```